# check using javascript if angular-sanitize.min.js was loaded from the CDN

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cdn

I know we can check if `angular.min.js` was loaded from CDN or not by using

```
if(!window.angular){
//download it from another source
}
```

But what if the situation is that the first file, `angular.modified.min.js` is always loaded locally. I mean How to check if the second file, `angular-sanitize.min.js` was loaded successfully from CDN?

What's the best javascript way to check?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngSanitize registers itself to angular when loaded. Check for any available modules in module.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    try{
        angular.module("ngSanitize") 
    }catch(err){
        console.log("ngSanitize error", err);
    }

});
```

I would use bower and grunt (or the like) to manage this though. Run time is a poor time to check for fractured lib issues.